# How do I make Tramp stop mangling my PATH?

Tags: tramp, ssh

Tramp is very tenacious in overriding the PATH setting of a remote
machine.  How can I completely disable this, so that Tramp's PATH is
identical to what I get when I manually log in with ssh on the
terminal?

The `~/.bashrc` in my remote machine looks as follows:

```bash
export PATH1=$PATH
# activate some Python virtualenvs, etc...
export PATH2=$PATH
```

I want the final PATH to be PATH2.  The closest I can get to that is
when setting `tramp-remote-path` to the value
`'(tramp-own-remote-path)`, in which case my PATH ends up being
identical to PATH1.  (I'm checking this by doing `M-x compile RET env RET` while editing a remote file.)

One interesting solution (with other applications as well) would be to
stipulate, as a directory or connection-local variable, an additional
rc file on the remote machine that is sourced every time Tramp
connects.  Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

Short solution: add all PATH-related settings to `~/.profile` instead of `~/.bashrc`, and make sure the former is `sh`-compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting idea. I have added it to the TODO list of Tramp. If you want to discuss further, I invite you to the `<tramp-devel@gnu.org>` mailing list. SX is not intended for longer discussions.

Comment: Do you consider this just a bug, or would you like more details about my motivation here? In the latter case, I'd be happy to discuss it on the mailing list.

Comment: Tramp's path-munging was killing my ability to use M-x compile to build anything on the remote machine because it was nuking the path to gcc etc (I use devtoolset-n on CentOS to get gcc-n for different versions).  My sledgehammer approach in emacs-27.2 was to put this in my .emacs - `(eval-after-load "tramp-sh" '(defun tramp-set-remote-path(vec)))` - BOOM!